# Cannot install pip centos 6.7

Tags: python, centos, installation, pip

I try to install pip on my centos 6.7 computer but run into the issue below.

So it seems like I have the wrong version of python. But if I check with python --version I get that I have version 2.7. So what should I do?????

Kind regards,
Anders

```
[epic@localhost opt]$ sudo yum install -y python-pip
[sudo] password for epic: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not get metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64 error was
14: Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
 * base: ftp.lysator.liu.se
 * epel: ftp.uni-bayreuth.de
 * extras: ftp.lysator.liu.se
 * nux-dextop: li.nux.ro
 * updates: ftp.lysator.liu.se
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-pip.noarch 0:7.1.0-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python-setuptools for package: python-pip-7.1.0-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.6.49-1.el7.nux will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.7 for package: python-setuptools-0.6.49-1.el7.nux.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-setuptools-0.6.49-1.el7.nux.noarch (nux-dextop)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python3-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               python(abi) = 3.3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Try running it without the sudo - you shouldn't need to use sudo with `pip`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install_requirements_linux/)
I think you might need to Enable the [PyPA Copr Repo](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/pypa/pypa/) before installing pip on CentOS / Fedora

Answer (score 0):

work around:

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ sudo python get-pip.py
$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```